# What does $\Bbb Z_7$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

What does $\Bbb Z_7$ mean? Does it mean that it contains $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$? I just want to know what it mean

Comment: What happened to the $7$-adic integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some accounts $\mathbb Z_7$ contains just $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,$ but one thinks of those as representing "congruence classes":
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{representative} & \text{congruence class} \\
\hline \vphantom{\dfrac {\displaystyle\sum} 1}
0 & \{\,0, \pm7,\pm14,\pm21,\pm28,\pm35,\ldots \,\} \text{ (multiples of 7)} \\[8pt]
1 & \{\, 1, 1\pm7, 1\pm14, 1\pm21, \ldots \,\} = \{\, \ldots, -13,-6,1,8,15,\ldots \,\} \\[8pt]
2 & \{\, 2, 2\pm7, 2\pm14, 2\pm21,\ldots \,\} = \{\,\ldots, -12, -5, 2, 9, 16, \ldots  \,\} \\[8pt]
3 & \{\, 3, 3\pm7, 3\pm14, 3\pm21,\ldots \,\} = \{\,\ldots, -11, -4, 3, 10, 17, \ldots  \,\} \\[8pt]
4 & \{\, 4, 4\pm7, 4\pm14, 4\pm21,\ldots \,\} = \{\,\ldots, -10, -3, 4, 11, 18, \ldots  \,\} \\[8pt]
5 & \{\, 5, 5\pm7, 5\pm14, 5\pm21,\ldots \,\} = \{\,\ldots, -9, -2, 5, 12, 19, \ldots  \,\} \\[8pt]
6 & \{\, 6, 6\pm7, 6\pm14, 6\pm21,\ldots \,\} = \{\,\ldots,-15, -8, -1, 6, 13, 16, \ldots  \,\}
\end{array}
$$
If we were to take this table one step further and include $7,$ we would be back to the same congruence class we started with, represented by $0.$

One says that two numbers belonging to the same congruence class are congruent to each other modulo $7.$ For example, $11$ and $18$ are congruent to each other. One writes:
$$
(18\equiv 11) \pmod 7.
$$
Or one writes
$$
18\equiv 11 \pmod 7.
$$
I used parentheses the first time in order to be explicit about the syntax, since sometimes people mistakenly think it means this: $\require{cancel} \xcancel{18 \equiv (11\bmod 7)},$ and that leads to confusions that have been the subject of questions posted here.

One can add, subtract, or multiply congruence classes.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_7$ usually denotes the group of integers modulo $7$. That means you partition the integers into equivalence classes. You do so by looking at each integer and check what it gives as a remainder when you divide by $7$. From each class we can pick a representative number and we usually choose the smallest from each class. So the members are $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. $7$ gives remainder $0$ when you divide by $7$ so it is in the class of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_7$ is the set of residue classes modulo $7$. So $$\Bbb Z_7=\{[0]_7,[1]_7,[2]_7,[3]_7,[4]_7,[5]_7,[6]_7\}$$ where $[a]_7$ is the residue class of $a\in\Bbb Z$ modulo $7$. However, we often just write $\Bbb Z_7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and it is implicit that these are residue classes we are talking about.

Note that $7=0$ in $\Bbb Z_7$, so when you include $7$ and $0$ in your set, they are the same element.

Comment: So 14 = 0, 15 = 1, -1 = 6, -2 = 5 ?

Comment: @JonD yessir! If $a$ and $b$ leave the same remainder when divided by $7$, then $a=b$ in $\Bbb Z_7$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the set of natural numbers that leave a remainder when you divide by $7$, or the set of integers modulo $7$ if you want to be a bit more formal. So
$$\Bbb Z_7=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$$

Note that $7$ is not in this set as having a remainder of $7$ is the same as having a remainder of $0$ when you divide by $7$.

Comment: According to your definition $\mathbb Z_7\subset\mathbb Z$. That's not so handsome if you want to look at it as a ring, though. Cumbersome definitions for multiplication and addition. I would plead for $\mathbb Z_7=\mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ah right, I see. Just out of interest then, how should I modify it in order to avoid such a complication?

Comment: If you stick to $\mathbb Z_7\subset\mathbb Z$ then you can overline the addition and multiplication to make clear that they are not the usual addition and multiplication in $\mathbb Z$: e.g. $5\bar+4=2$. If you choose my side then you can overline the elements to make clear that they are not really elements of $\mathbb Z$: e.g. $\bar5+\bar4=\bar2$

Answer (score 1):

#### From the Axioms

Since this question is tagged [group-theory](/questions/tagged/group-theory), the most appropriate answer is likely that $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is the abelian group with seven elements.  Taking this apart a little, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a *set* which contains seven elements.  So we could write it as a set as (for example)
$$
\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\{a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\{ \ast,\square,\spadesuit,\heartsuit,\diamondsuit,\clubsuit,\nabla \}.
$$
In addition to being a set with seven elements, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ also has the structure of an *abelian group*.  This means that there is a binary operation $+$ on $\mathbb{Z}_7$ which satisfies the following axioms:

1. (Closure) If $x$ and $y$ are any two elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$, then $x+y$ is also an element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$.
2. (Associativity) If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$, then
   $$ (x+y) + z = z + (y+z); $$
   that is, we can move parentheses around without penalty.
3. (Identity) There exists a special element $\mathbb{0}$ such that
   $$ \mathbb{0} + x = x + \mathbb{0} = x $$
   for all $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.  This element is called the *identity element*.
4. (Inverse) If $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$, then there exists an element $-x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ such that
   $$ x + (-x) = \mathbb{0}. $$
   That is, each element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ has an *inverse*.
5. (Commutativity) For all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, we have
   $$ x + y = y + x. $$
   That is, the binary operation is commutative, and we can "add things up" in any order.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_7$ must have a lot of the same properties that we might expect from the integers, it is reasonable to represent it with a set that looks like integers.  Thus we can very reasonably write
$$ \mathbb{Z}_7 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} $$
as a set.  For the group structure, consider the following addition table:
$$ \begin{array}{r|rrrrrrr}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{array}
$$
Notice that $0 + x = x + 0 = x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_7$, and that each element has an inverse (this can be seen by noting that there is a zero in each row).  Closure should be more-or-less obvious, and associativity and commutativity can be checked by brute force.  Thus we can define $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to be the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ together with the operation $+$ satisfying the above table.

---

#### As a Quotient Group

A bit more abstractly, we can define $\mathbb{Z}_7$ to be the *quotient group* of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the subgroup generated by $7$.  The actual construction is a little more abstract, but the basic outline is as follows:  $\mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group.  We say that two integers are *equivalent* modulo 7 if their difference is divisible by 7.  For example, 23 and 37 are equivalent modulo 7, as
$$ 37 - 23 = 14 = 2\cdot 7. $$
For simplicity, we write
$$ 37 \equiv 23 \pmod{7}, $$
which is read "37 is equivalent to 23 modulo 7."  From this definition, it can be shown that if $x$ is an integer, then the set of integers that are equivalent to $x$ is the set
$$ \{ x+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z} \}. $$
That is, $x$ plus any integer multiple of $7$ will be equivalent to $x$ modulo 7.  This equivalence relation partitions the integers into seven disjoint classes:
\begin{align}
[0]_7 &:= \{7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} &&(\text{multiples of 7})\\
[1]_7 &:= \{1+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} &&(\text{multiples of 7, plus 1})\\
[2]_7 &:= \{2+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} &&(\text{and so on})\\
[3]_7 &:= \{3+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
[4]_7 &:= \{4+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
[5]_7 &:= \{5+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\} \\
[6]_7 &:= \{6+7k \mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}
\end{align}
Next, observe that if $x \in [a]_7$ and $y\in [b]_7$, then
$$ (x+y) \in [a+b]_7. $$
It then follows that the set $\{ [0]_7, [1]_7, \dotsc, [6]_7\}$, together with the binary operation $\oplus$ defined by
$$ [a]_7 \oplus [b]_7 := [a+b]_7, $$
satisfy the axioms of an abelian group.  We are using the funny addition symbol $\oplus$ here in order to distinguish the addition of equivalence classes from the usual addition of integers.  The addition within square braces (i.e. in the term $[a+b]_7$) is the usual addition.  In this construction, we are starting with a "big" group (the integers), then "modding out" by a subgroup (the multiples of 7).  In notation, we might write this as
$$ \mathbb{Z}/\langle 7 \rangle
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\mathbb{Z}/7. $$
The above is a little hand-wavy, but it can be made rigorous.  Note that $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 7 \rangle$ is an abelian group with 7 elements.  It is natural to ask if it is the "same" as the group defined previously.

Indeed, if $\{0,1,\dotsc,6\}$ is the set of seven elements with addition as defined in the table above, the map
$$ \varphi: \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} \to \{ [0]_7,[1]_7,[2]_7,[3]_7,[4]_7,[5]_7,[6]_7\} $$
defined by
$\varphi(a) = [a]_7$ is an *isomorphism* of groups.  This means that the groups
$$ (\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}, +)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
( \{ [0]_7,[1]_7,[2]_7,[3]_7,[4]_7,[5]_7,[6]_7\}, \oplus )
$$
cannot be distinguished from each other.  Huzzah!

---

#### And Now for Something Completely Different

In addition to the above, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is also used to denote the $7$-adic integers.  Because I am analyst (and not an algebraist), I'll describe the metric spaces version of the $7$-adic numbers, though do note that they can *also* be constructed in a more algebra-flavoured manner (as the inverse limit of some sequence of rings, plus a little more abstract nonsense).

If $x$ is any rational number, then there is a unique integer (which could be negative, or zero) such that
$$ x = 7^n \frac{a}{b}, $$
where $a$ and $b$ are integers which are not divisible by $7$.  We define the *$7$-adic absolute value* of $x$ to be
$$ |x|_7 := 7^{-n}. $$
Basically, the $7$-adic absolute value measure how "divisible" a rational number is by $7$.  The more divisible it is, the smaller it is.  More generally, if $p$ is any prime number, we can define a $p$-adic absolute value which measures how divisible rational numbers are by $p$.  In some sense, the $p$-adic absolute value measures the "$p$-ness" of a rational number (let that one sink in for a moment).

The $7$-adic absolute value gives us a way of describing how big or small rational numbers are, which can be used to determine a distance between two rational numbers.  Specifically, the function
$$ d_7(x,y) := |x-y|_7 $$
defines a *metric* on $\mathbb{Q}$, analogous to the way that the "usual" absolute value can be used to define a metric.  As with the usual absolute value, the metric obtained from the $7$-adic absolute value does not turn the rational numbers into a *complete* metric space:  there are sequences of rational numbers that get "close together" (in a certain technical sense), but which do not converge to a rational limit.  However, we can "complete" the rational numbers using a relatively straightforward technique.  Once we do this, we obtain a set denoted $\mathbb{Q}_7$, called the *$7$-adic numbers*.  (Again, by analogy, the usual absolute value on $\mathbb{Q}$ induced an incomplete metric which can be completed in order to obtain the real numbers.)

In the $7$-adic numbers, the unit ball (the set of $7$-adic numbers less than or equal one unit from zero) plays a special role.  From a metric point of view, a distinguished ball is nice to have, but it turns out that this unit ball also has really nice algebraic structure.  Because of this, it gets special notation:
$$ \mathbb{Z}_7 = B_{\le}(0,1) = \{ x\in\mathbb{Q}_p \mid |x|_7 \le 1 \}. $$
Note that this unit ball—called the *$7$-adic integers* (for reasons that are more clear if you construct the $7$-adic numbers algebraically, rather than analytically)—is *also* denoted by the symbol $\mathbb{Z}_7$.  However, this object is very different from the group $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 7 \rangle$, thus context is important.